# sent an id to a js function. Lost with the ' and the "

Tags: javascript, php, html

it's about 30 minutes that im searching for the issue....

```
foreach($resultat as $ligne) {  
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TD><a href='javascript:selectResources('".($ligne['ID'])."')'>".($ligne['login'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['queen'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['worker'])."</TD>
      <TD>".($ligne['warrior'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['pollen'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['wax'])."</TD>";
     echo "</TR>";
}
```

And the problem is there : `"<TD><a href='javascript:selectResources('".($ligne['ID'])."')'>"`

Im trying to take the sql ID about the user and send it in parameters to a javascript function, but im lost with the ' " ...

It's say unexpected end of input, and if i delete this part it works....

Car someone help me, giving an easier way or just explaning how correctly works the ' and " .... thx

Comment: Your single/double quotes are wrong.

Comment: @Beterraba I guess that's what the question is about: ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code outputs the following HTML:

```
<TD><a href='javascript:selectResources('id')'>login</TD>
```

This is not valid HTML. Change one pair of single quotes to double quotes, e.g. the ones used for the `href` attribute:

```
echo "<TD><a href=\"javascript:selectResources('".($ligne['ID'])."')\">".($ligne['login'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['queen'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['worker'])."</TD>
  <TD>".($ligne['warrior'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['pollen'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['wax'])."</TD>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your single and double quotes you'll need to escape them.
`\'` and `\"`

```
"<TD><a href='javascript:selectResources(\'\".($ligne['ID']).\"\')'>"
```

Comment: My rep isn't high enough to just add a comment, which what I would've preferred to do.  Sorry.

Comment: this happens a lot. You need to **earn** the comment privilege. This is designed to prevent spam. But it does not mean that you should add a bad answer and not expect down votes. Anyway, I can see you've corrected your answer so have adjusted my vote accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I admit, I was a bit rash in answering.  Advice taken.

Answer (score 0):

You quotes are wrong. I will separete for the sake of readability:

```
echo "<TD>";
echo "<a href='javascript:selectResources(\"" . ($ligne['ID']) . "\")'>";
echo ($ligne['login']);
echo "</TD><TD>".($ligne['queen'])."</TD><TD>".($ligne['worker'])."</TD>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just embed the ID in the html and query it through the event.

```
<a href="javascript:click();" id="id_here">link</a>

function click(event){
    var sId = $(event.target).attr("id");
}
```